# Comparing consequent strings in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

Right now I have a string array and I want to loop through the string array and compare the value at one index with the value at the next index. For example, if I was doing this in Java, the code would be something like this:

```
string[] some = ["IP", "IP", "ADDRESS", "2342.42.2", "IP", "ASDF"];
for (int i = 0 ; i < some.length() ; i++)
    if (some[i] == "IP" && some[i+1] == "ADDRESS")
        int ipaddress = some[i+2];
```

I know that Python is a bit different, but basically I am trying to find the first IP ADDRESS. How can I compare the current element and the next one in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct translation of your code. In python [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) iterates over a list as index,value pairs.

```
>>> some = ["IP", "IP", "ADDRESS", "2342.42.2", "IP", "ASDF"];
>>> for i,v in enumerate(some):
...     if v=="IP" and some[i+1] == "ADDRESS": 
...         ipaddress = some[i+2]
... 
>>> ipaddress
'2342.42.2'
```

However you may consider end cases where there is no such stuff. So you may as well so `for i,v in enumerate(some[:-2])`. This will ensure that you will not get out of the bounds of the list otherwise you will get an `IndexError`

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out right after I asked the question...silly on my part. I did something like this:

`for index in range(len(datainarray)):
  print 'Current string :' , datainarray[index]
  if datainarray[index] == "IP" and datainarray[index + 1] == "ADDRESS":
   print "HERES ONE"`

Comment: Using `enumerate` is the preferred way in Python

Comment: Oh alright. Will look into that and use that instead then!